# Selecting Item that has Max of one but Min of another in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that lists players on a team, the number of years on the team, and the number of points scored. What I'm trying to do is return the person that has the most number of points scored and the least number of years on the team. This is what I've done:

```
SELECT player
FROM team
GROUP BY player
HAVING MAX(points) and MIN(years);
```

Example of a table and expected output:

```
player | years | points
-------+-------+---------    
p1     |    2  |  200 
p2     |    5  |   10
p3     |    1  |  500
```

From this I expect to get back p3 since they have the min for years and the max for points.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Access.

Comment: What is more important, MAX(points) or MIN(years)?

Comment: I suppose OP wants both, i.e. either max points or min years.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example].

Comment: I want both - select the one player that has the most points and the least number of years.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that.

Comment: In your example p3 has the least years, but does *not* have the most points at 50.  Player p1 has the most points at 200.  Do you mean to say “*return the player who has the most points among thos who have the least years?*”.

Comment: To explain “*most points and least years*” are contradictory conditions when stated like that, because they could be two different players.  To resolve it, you either need to prioritize one over the other, or provide a formula that takes both years and points and returns a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you players with max points, and also players with min years:

```
SELECT player, points, years
FROM team
where points = (select max(points) from team)
   or years = (select min(years) from team)
```

Comment: I think he wants both conditions to be satisfied, so it should have 'AND' instead of 'OR'

Comment: @AndreiManolache, that would probably return zero rows, as long as the youngest person doesn't have the most points.